Why are questions now highlighted as to last active User, rather than the OP?
I have noticed that the list of questions now has the user attached being the last person to actively contribute to the uestion rather than, as before, the OP being attached to the question.
Is this just on SE-BH and SE-C or is it common, now, to the whole of Stack Exchange ?

Reported on Meta SE: "Newest Questions" tab showing last active user instead of the asker

@AndrewT. Yes. That is the same question I have asked. The change came in about 07/12/24 as the question on Meta states.

Looks like it has now been resolved, thanks for flagging

Do you mean these parts saying "Dottard answered 3 hours ago" or "Michael Mior modified 3 hours ago"? It's always been that way.


Thank you, but please see as supplied above by @Andrew T.
